# Custom [admin] interfaces with Django?

Tags: django, interface, customization, admin

I've been playing around with python/django for the last couple of weeks and whilst the overall structure and makeup of the framework is making sense I'm rather confused on how to create advanced interfaces (in relation to tasks administrators would perform). One trivial example I'm playing around with at the moment is a bulk csv product import for different suppliers which will update various fields of a particular product (keeping track of any changes), creating items where they don't already exist and applying other business logic etc.

With the data successfully in the database and the models reflecting this I envisage a view whereby one could select a supplier from a drop down, which would load all the products silently in the background and display a datagrid on success. The user could then interact with each product individually, for example selecting would display a stacked line chart of pricing history above the datagrid and an optional fly-in panel to the right with options to update prices, add notes etc.

Are there any best practice approaches for achieving something along these lines, does one create custom views/templates or put some heavy lifting into overriding the default Django admin functionality?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- [Create a custom django admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) that will appear as an option in the changelist page dropdown menu (of the `Supplier` model for example.) You can then apply this action to the selected rows. You can also [have intermediate pages when using admin actions](http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/)
- [You can hook your own views into the django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) for particular models and and then [overwrite the appropriate django admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) to link the two together